# Cant get Telegram Channel Users with GetParticipantsRequest (Telethon API)

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, python-telegram-bot, telethon

I'am using [Telethon AP](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon)I and getting a privilege error in the function GetParticipantsRequest when I try to get the users inside my own telegram **channel**, in which I'am Admin

```
telethon.errors.rpc_error_list.ChatAdminRequiredError: (ChatAdminRequiredError(...), 'Chat admin privileges are required to do that in the specified chat (for e
xample, to send a message in a channel which is not yours)')
```

Makes no sense because when I do the same code routine with a telegram group of mine, it works like a charm.

Here goes the routine:

```
def getUserNames(channel):
offset = 0
limit = 100
all_participants = []
selected_participants = []
channel = client(ResolveUsernameRequest(channel))
channel = InputChannel(channel.chats[0].id, channel.chats[0].access_hash)       

while True:
    participants = client(
        GetParticipantsRequest(channel, ChannelParticipantsSearch(''), offset, limit, 0)
    )
    if not participants.users:
        break
    all_participants.extend(participants.users)
    offset += len(participants.users)

if len(all_participants):
    for x in all_participants:
        if x.username: selected_participants.append(x.username)
    print (selected_participants)
    return selected_participants
else:
    return -1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use can use this code for get all participants :

```
from telethon import TelegramClient
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetParticipantsRequest
from telethon.tl.functions.channels import GetFullChannelRequest
from telethon.tl.types import ChannelParticipantsSearch

api_id = XXXXX
api_hash = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
phone_number = '+98XXXXXXXX'
################################################
channel_username = 'tehrandb'
################################################

client = TelegramClient('session_name',api_id,api_hash)

assert client.connect()
if not client.is_user_authorized():
    client.send_code_request(phone_number)
    me = client.sign_in(phone_number, input('Enter code: '))

# ---------------------------------------
offset = 0
limit = 200
my_filter = ChannelParticipantsSearch('')
all_participants = []
while_condition = True
# ---------------------------------------
channel = client(GetFullChannelRequest(channel_username))
while while_condition:
    participants = client(GetParticipantsRequest(channel=channel_username, filter=my_filter, offset=offset, limit=limit, hash=0))
    all_participants.extend(participants.users)
    offset += len(participants.users)
    if len(participants.users) < limit:
         while_condition = False
```

I used ‍`Telethon V0.19`, but the previous versions are pretty much the same

Comment: `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'TelegramBaseClient.connect' was never awaited
  assert client.connect()
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'UserMethods.is_user_authorized' was never awaited
  if not client.is_user_authorized():
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
 line 30, in <module>
    all_participants.extend(participants.users)
AttributeError: 'coroutine' object has no attribute 'users'`